WireGuard PostUp script works strange on startup
In the wg0.conf:
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.2 -p udp -m udp -d 10.10.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.1.2
But in iptables i see:
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 52 packets, 8705 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 SNAT       udp  --  any    any     192.168.0.0/24       10.10.10.0/24        to:10.10.10.22

Instead of 10.10.1.0/24 i got 10.10.10.0/24, and instaed of 10.10.1.2 got 10.10.10.22
I tryed to copy the script and paste it manually. And it works nice. I alse restarted the wg service, in order to call PostUp scripts again systemctl reload wg-quick@wg0, all ok, the rule added to iptables like it should be. The problem exists only in boot time.
